# Populating a UITableView from arrays

Tags: iphone, arrays, uitableview, ios, loops

I need help with the following code i am using hpple to parse html.
and i need help utilizing the data.

```
-(void) whatever{
NSData *htmlData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.objectgraph.com/contact.html"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *titles  = [xpathParser search:@"//h3"]; // get the page title - this is xpath     notation
TFHppleElement *title = [titles objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myTitles = [title content];

NSArray *articles  = [xpathParser search:@"//h4"]; // get the page article - this is xpath     notation
TFHppleElement *article = [articles objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myArtical = [article content];
```

i want to create and populate a table from the array "titles"
Then be able to click the item on the table to load a subview that should show the corresponding artical at the same index?

I'd like to do this programatically or using IB

can anyone suggest some sample code or a tutorial?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [titles count];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{



        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

        UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        }


    cell.textLabel.text = [titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

/* here pop up Your subview with corresponding  value  from the array with array index indexpath.row ..*/

}
```

Comment: Thats great rajesh, will this create the table for me or do i need to create the tableview this in interface builder? do i need to call these? sorry for my ignorance im new to IOS dev

Comment: no you need to creat a table view in didload .in your .h file put UITbaleView *yourtableView; and in .m file under viewDidLoad method put yourtableView =[ [UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(put your own coordinates )]; and then yourtableView.delegate = self; then [self.view addSubView:yourTableView]; and int my answer UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
 replace  the  'tableView' with yourTableView. k ? please let me know if ny questions?

Comment: Thanks rajesh, i used your above code and linked it with a table in interface builder! it works perfectly :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a general approach, you simply need to set the relevant controller class as a delegate for the UITableView in question and then implement the following methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

However, I'd recommend reading Apple's [Table View Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) - it'll elucidate a lot more than a simple code sample, and is reasonably easy to follow.

Once you've done that, if you're still after sample code simply download one of the projects within the "Related sample code" section of the [UITableView Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). (If you do this within Apple's doc viewer in Xcode it automates the download, etc. and will bring up the project in Xcode for you.)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource in .h file where you are creating tableview and declare an NSarray to store the table values,and in .m file of viedidload function you need to intialise the array with objects (arr_name=[NSArray alloc]initwith
Objects:@"one",@"two",nil) and you have to place these three methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath